# Создание шаблона для ListBox (Select)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, javascript

```
Добрый день. Подскажите, как на JS/Jquery/Сss создать шаблон ListBox-а, где бы в каждом элементе была фотография, фио, и ещё какие-нибудь данные. Как вконтакте или фейсбуке список друзей, например.
Спасибо.
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять готовый плагин. Например, [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating) или [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo)